# Ajax function hangs on loop

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, loops

I have a little script in a html page that loops through an array, it runs an ajax function to  check if a file is there, if it is..it prints a number off the array; if not it prints 0.  The  problem is that it just hangs (browser just sits there loading forever) after the first iteration.  Is there a way to close the connection?  I'm rather new to Ajax, so thanks for the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                        
var cnt = 0;                                                                                                                                         
var getNum;
var num = [25, 15, 24, 16, 23, 17, 22, 18, 21, 19, 20];
var response = 1;

function getAjax(sales, cnt, getNum){

    loadDoc(response);

    if(response == 1 )
    {

        if(cnt >= 11)
        {
            cnt = 0; 
        }
        else
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        getNum = num[cnt];
    }
    else{
        getNum = 0;
    }

    document.write(getNum + '<br/>');
}


function loadDoc(response)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari                                                                                                                  
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5                                                                                                                                              
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            response = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            response = 0;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","randomFile.js",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function runIt(num, cnt, getNum, response){
   setTimeout('getAjax(num, cnt, getNum)', 3000);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="alert"></div>
  <button type="button" onclick="runIt(num, cnt, getNum, response)">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use jquery AJAX `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` or `$.get()`, may be that handles AJAX more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequests are asynchronous. This means everything here

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        response = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        response = 0;
    }
}
```

is run a period of time **after** the request is made. More specifically:

```
...
loadDoc(response);

// the XMLHttpRequest might not have finished within this gap

if(response == 1 ) // <----- response might have not been updated yet
...
```

Therefore, if you immediately check the `response`, it might not have been updated yet. Instead, everything that needs to be run that depends on the response should be placed in the callback function shown above. This includes your counter incrementing logic.

Additionally, you passed the `response` variable into `loadDoc`, which serves no purpose since `response` is a global variable already.

Comment: Yeah I know about the globals...I just use it while developing to remind myself what variables I've passed in there.  So after reading up on it I should be doing everything within:
         if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
              }